# Using CSS id selector to style Gridview control

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have an existing CSS file with these 2 id selectors:

```
#TableHead {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #000000;
border-top-width: thin;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #A9AAAA;
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #A9AAAA;
}

#TableDivs {
border-bottom-width: 1px;
font-size:11px;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-bottom-color: #A9AAAA;
}
```

I need to use "TableHead" to style Gridview header and "TableDivs" to style the rest of the Gridview control.
I am able to use TableDivs by enclosing the gridview in  section.
How can I use TableHead to style the header? Where should I specify id="TableHead"?

The rendered source code of Gridview after adding  is:

```
<div id="TableDivs">
  <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="0" id="ctl00_Main_GridView1" style="border-width:0px;font-weight:normal;border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
      <th align="left" scope="col">
          <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$GridView1','Sort$FileName')">File Name</a>
        </th>
        <th align="left" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$GridView1','Sort$Description')">Description</a>
        </th>
        <th align="left" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$GridView1','Sort$GroupName')">Folder Name</a>
        </th>
        <th align="left" scope="col">
          <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$GridView1','Sort$TimeAdded')">Date Added</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td style="width:30%;">
          <a id="ctl00_Main_GridView1_ctl02_btnDownload" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$GridView1$ctl02$btnDownload','')">2.txt</a>
        </td>
        <td style="width:40%;">222222</td><td style="width:25%;">group11</td>
        <td style="width:5%;">
          <span id="ctl00_Main_GridView1_ctl02_lblDateAdded"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      ...
    </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView HeaderStyle-CssClass="your_class" ></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. This will work only if I'm using css class selector. But in my case, I have to use css id selector.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use

```
Gridview .table, Gridview .th, Gridview .tr, Gridview .tr
```

selectors. This will help you select the gridview or all similar gridviews and give them a common look and feel.

It also allows CSS to do the styling instead of writing code in .NET and specifying the class.

Comment: Ideally, that should be done. But the page I'm developing is an addition to existing website and the css files are common to all the pages. So, I cannot change the css files.

Comment: looks from the comments that you are working with Ids : so you set the GridView Id but you can not set the ids for the table header or the table, you will have to use css class or update the css file

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridId" runat="server" >
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="TableHead" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="TableDivs" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. This will work only if I'm using css class selector. But in my case, I have to use css id selector.

Comment: That's a CSS stuff, and has nothing to do with grid. Change your CSS selectors to target the grid. Can you give us the rendered result of your grid (a sample)

Comment: Added in the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="TableDivs" runat="server" >
    use some js to get the parent of ths or just thead(if GridView can export thead), then add #TableHead to the element.
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I didn't understand. If I change the Gridview ID to "TableDivs", I'll have to change it everywhere in my code. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Maybe can use javascript to get tbody and add #TableDivs too.  But one id only be used in a document one time, if #TableDivs will be everywhere, maybe need to change css.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. 
Finally I had no choice but to modify all the css files and add new class selectors, because I had no way of using the id selectors. I used the new class selectors in GridView's HeaderStyle, RowStyle, PagerStyle cssclass attribute.
It is working fine now.